# how to edit bootstrap.min.css in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to wordpress and I am doing a site on zalive theme.

There is a default slider in the theme.When I change the default image the picture size varies.When I inspect element, I can adjust the height and width of the image.But it is in bootstrap.min.css. Where can I edit this file? When I check the appearance->editor I can see style.css,but not bootstrap.min.css.I tried to open the link for bootsrap.min.css, it opens but I can't edit anything.please help.

The site is uploaded to server by my senior from a different system and he only gave me username and password to work on this site.Does that have anything to do with locating bootstrap.min.css file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

from my knowledge wordpress do not give you access to all the .css files, your going to need to ftp into the server or login to your hosting file manager to edit to edit the bootstrap file.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have access to the server / ftp, you can't update that file.

Alternatively, you can install plugin like this https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/ and override the CSS with your own